# Is this the place for Neuroscience related questions?

Tags: discussion

Is this the place for Neuroscience related questions? e.g. fMRI preprocessing/analysis methods and such like? I see there's no neuroscience tag yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is if it's a signal processing question that comes from neuroscience. In case of fMRI, I think that a [medical-imaging](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/medical-imaging) tag would be more appropriate.

Comment: Ok thanks hadn't seen that tag

Comment: It doesn't exist. I meant to say that creating such tag would be more appropriate.